# Find dropped packets from pcapng-dump

Tags: wireshark, pcap

I need to get a dropped packet count out of captured pcapng file. I know it is stored in there, because when I open it in wireshark and go to "Comments Summary" I find the following:

```
Capture:
   OS: 64-bit Windows 7 Service Pack 1, build 7601
   Capture application: Dumpcap 1.12.6 (v1.12.6-0-gee1fce6 from master-1.12)

   \Device\NPF_{2005D0F6-4603-45A3-829F-FA6C40692419}:
      Dropped packets: 1 (0.962%)
      Capture filter: none
      Link type: Ethernet
      Packet size limit 262144 bytes
```

However, I can't run wireshark to get this info, I need it as a stdout output like given from capinfos. When I run capinfos and get all the statisics I could want out of the file, except for this dropped packet count.

I find this strange. Does this mean the capinfos-program is outdated and can't extract this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this mean the capinfos-program is outdated

No.

> and can't extract this information?

Yes.

It's not so much that it's outdated that it hasn't been changed to report that information.  File an enhancement request at [the Wireshark Bugzilla](http://bugs.wireshark.org).

Comment: I downloaded the source code and noticed that there is a drop_packets-field in the struct holding the capinfo, but it's just not printed. Next task will be to build wireshark with my modifications :P